# Booting from USB stick always boots to main SSD drive

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, usb

I had two partitions with dual boot Windows/Linux (Manjaro). I also had Linux bootloader to choose which OS to start. I wanted to try some other Linux distribution so I have deleted my previous Linux partition but I have also deleted bootloader so I couldn't also boot to Windows.

I used the USB flash drive with the new OS in live mode and from the terminal I did:

```
sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
```

Now I can boot into Windows normally but when I am trying to boot from my USB flash drive device to install the Linux OS, it is always leads to Windows again.

I have also tried some other PC and it boots properly from the USB.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my internal 1TB HDD with 500 GB Samsung 850 EVO.

I decided not to clone but I went to install Windows 10 as fresh.

All went well but I noticed that when I remove my external USB, which I used for installing Windows 10, the SSD doesn't boot.

It works only when the boot stick is present. Any idea how I could fix this?